# Table with overflow auto hides content with position absolute

Tags: html, css

The fiddle explains the problem. I have a scrollable table and a context menu inside it, but with the overflow-x: auto, this "context menu" stop being visible.

```css
table {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h2>ABSOLUTE Position Problem</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="position: absolute">
        <div class="absoluteElement">
          Content will scroll with the bar
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohwy3z6L/16/

How to make a scroll on the table and keep the context menu appearing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question right, but here is what I've managed to do, say if something is wrong and I'll try and fix it.

```css
tr {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  /* Imagine a dropdown/context menu on the grid here */
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
}

.absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  /* Imagine a dropdowncontext menu on the grid here */
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>RELATIVE Position Problem</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="relativeElement">
          Content will cut here
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>ABSOLUTE Position Problem</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="position: relative">
        <div class="absoluteElement">
          Content will scroll with the bar
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I tried your example but the horizontal scrollbar on the table is not appearing. I need to have a table with horizontal scroll and a flotant content inside the first column of each row. But in this case, the content hides because of the overflow-x, even setting a overflow-y: visible, for example. Did you get the problem?

Comment: So you want to make a scroll that goes from left to right?

Comment: Yes! Actually, I figured out a solution here and it worked for me on IE11/Firefox/Chrome. What I did was to remove a position: relative from the table itself, put my flotant content with position: absolute and top: auto (fixing the top with negative values on margin-top, and the parent of the absolute content I used position: static, so the element is not affected by the scroll anymore and it's flotant again.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Update the question with the solution you've found.